# Android: Templating with XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

so I'm pretty new to Android Development, and I have the following situation:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/child_1" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="">

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="">
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that I have to repeat this **Horizontal** LinearLayout an unknown amount of times, dynamically adding the text fields of the TextView and Button for each new instance. Each new instance of the **Horizontal** LinearLayout has to be added to an existing **Vertical** LinearLayout.

So the initial Vertical LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Then based on the dynamic implementation:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/child_1">        
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/child_2">        
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there any way that this can be done as I described? The XML elements that I used in the example are base case. The ones I am actually using have styling attributes associated to them, so I would just like to create the first **Horizontal** LinearLayout in XML then programmatically access it, add the required fields, then set it as a child of the **Vertical** LinearLayout.

Comment: Use [List View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) instead. You can customize the appearance of each row according to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the childs dynamically and add them to the parent vertical LinearLayout.
Please check the following code: I used a TextView and a Spinner for each created row:

```
    //--- Row Layout ---
    LinearLayout rowLayout = null;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams rowLayoutparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    /** Create the TextViews and Spinners */
    for (int j=0; j<gameArray.length; j++) {   
       //Create new row
       rowLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
       rowLayout.setLayoutParams(rowLayoutparams);
       rowLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        //--- TEXT VIEW ---
        TextView myTextView = new TextView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        myTextView.setId(j);
        myTextView.setText("CONTENT");
        myTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        //--- SPINNER ---
        spinnersArray[j] = new Spinner(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        spinnersArray[j].setId(j+100); //set a different ID
        //Populate the spinner here ...

        //--- LAYOUT PARAMS ---
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams itemParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);        //first and last item
        //edit the item params here ...

        //Add the params to the Views
        myTextView.setLayoutParams(itemParams);
        spinnersArray[j].setLayoutParams(itemParams);

        //--- Add the view to the Layout ---
        rowLayout.addView(myTextView);
        rowLayout.addView(spinnersArray[j]);

        //--- Add the row to the layout only if (NOT even) OR the chars are finished ---          
        ((LinearLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.parent)).addView(rowLayout);
    }
```